# Running React & Express in Docker without exposing multiple Ports

Tags: reactjs, docker, express, socket.io

We are currently working on this project: [Brainwriter](https://github.com/BuchholzTim/6-3-5-Brainwriter)

It's a React-Frontend with an Express-Server as Backend, which is using a postgres-database.

Currently I am running the project inside docker on my server. The Frontend runs on Port 3000, while the Backend runs on Port 3001. Ideally I'd like to only expose the Frontend-Port, but in its current state, when I stop exposing Port 3001, the Frontend cannot access the Backend anymore.

As I'm kinda new to Web-Dev & Docker as a whole I cannot figure out wheter the issue lies within my docker configuration or if it is a React-Express-Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a React-Express problem as currently, you are running both servers separately (React on Port `3000` and Express on port `30001`). and that is the reason you need to expose two different ports to access the services and for the frontend to access the backend.

To run it on 1 port, I would suggest, serve your React static files via express itself and then you don't have to expose 2 different ports. Only expose Express and that can serve the react application as well.

Below is the express method which can be used to serve your static files.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '$PATH_OF_STATIC_FILES')));
```

where `$PATH_OF_STATIC_FILES` can be `public` folder or `client` folder , basically where you will generate and keep the `bundle.js` and `index.html` and other static assets.

Have a look at the below articles, if you want a deep dive.

> Ref:- https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html (Express static Files)
>
> Ref:- https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-serve-react-from-same-origin/ (React with Express)